# .env file doesn't display custom environment variables

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, create-react-app

I have a .env file set up in my project 
[image: ENV FILE]

But when i console.log it i can only see the following object

```
{
  "NODE_ENV": "development",
  "PUBLIC_URL": ""
}
```

I tried using .env.local but the problem persists. I used `create-react-app` to bootstrap the react application

Comment: by default, you will not have access to env variables in `client-side`.  read [this](https://medium.com/@trekinbami/using-environment-variables-in-react-6b0a99d83cf5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your custom environment variables need to have the prefix `REACT_APP_`.

Like this:

```
REACT_APP_GOOGLE_MAP_KEY = asdfdtgsg34qrgaerg
```

[More about environment variables with create-react-app](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables)

Answer (score 0):

You many be missing any one of this

- The env file should be in your root (not in src)
- the env variable name should be prefixed with REACT_APP_
- You need to restart the server to reflect the changes.
- After that you can access the variable like this process.env.REACT_APP_SOME_VARIABLE in your CRA app